# Self referencing many to many relationships in Fluent NHibernate automapping automapping to 1:n and not n:n

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

The title pretty much explains it all, I have a Member object that references 'Friends' who are also type Member.

```
public class Member : Entity
    {
        public Member()
        {            
            Friends = new List<Member>();
        }

        public virtual IList<Member> Friends
        {
            get; set;
        }
     }
```

The schema generation tool makes it a 1:n relationship while it should be a n:n relationship i.e. a column is added to the member table called member_id and no connecting table is created.

Is there any way to make a Self referencing many to many relationships in Fluent NHibernate?

I tried using an override that I got as an answer before:

```
public class MemberOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Member>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Member> mapping)
    {
        mapping.HasManyToMany(m => m.Friends)
               .Table("MemberFriendsLinkTable");
    }
}
```

but I get the error message:

"NHibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for collection: Proj.BO.Member.Friends column: Member_id"

Thanks

**EDIT:** I found the answer, it's to put:

```
mapping.HasManyToMany(m => m.Friends).ParentKeyColumn("Member_Id").ChildKeyColumn("Friend_Id")
                   .Table("MemberFriendsLinkTable").Inverse().Cascade.SaveUpdate();
```

Comment: You can answer your own questions. Go ahead and put your solution in an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So that I don't have to see this question at the top of the "Unanswered NHibernate Questions" list anymore...

Eitan, the asker, discovered the solution to his own problem.  He needed to specify the `ParentKeyColumn` and `ChildKeyColumn` like so:

> **EDIT:** I found the answer, it's to put:
>
> ```
> mapping.HasManyToMany(m => m.Friends)
>     .ParentKeyColumn("Member_Id")
>     .ChildKeyColumn("Friend_Id")
>     .Table("MemberFriendsLinkTable")
>     .Inverse()
>     .Cascade.SaveUpdate();
> ```

FluentNHibernate by default names foreign key columns like so: `{className}_Id`.  Since both ends of the many-to-many were of the same type, it wanted to use the same column name, `Member_Id` for both columns.  Explicitly naming the columns circumvents this problem.

Comment: I found that adding either `ParentKeyColumn` or `ChildKeyColumn` is sufficient (if you provide a name different from the default of course)

Comment: The `.Inverse()` actually throw an exception in my case so I had to remove it, but apart from that this solution works wonderfully!

Answer (score 0):

```
References(x => x.Parent)
            .Class<Parent>()
            .Access.Property()
            .Cascade.None()
            .LazyLoad()
            .Not.Insert()
            .Not.Update()
            .Columns("PARENT_ID");

        HasMany(x => x.Children)
          .Access.Property()
          .AsBag()
          .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
          .LazyLoad()
          .Inverse()
          .Generic()
          .KeyColumns.Add("PARENT_ID", mapping => mapping.Name("PARENT_ID")
                                                               .SqlType("NUMBER")
                                                               .Not.Nullable());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I understand that, I have similar kind of issue with little bit of change. Can you please try to answer the question to the link

[Fluent nhibernate m-to-m mapping with external table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413690/fluent-nhibernate-m-to-m-mapping-with-external-table)