# Fluent nhibernate m-to-m mapping with external table

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have two tables in Oracle

```
Entity
----------
**EntityId** NUMBER(9), **EntityName** VARCHAR2

EntityLinks
--------------
**EntityLinkId** NUMBER(9),**ParentEntityId** NUMBER(9), **ChildEntityId** NUMBER(9)
```

Table EntityLinks will store ManyToMany relationship between various entities. **ParentEntityId** and **ChildEntityId** are having foreign key relationship with **Entity**.

I have below a below class for Entity as well

```
public class Entity
{
     public virtual int EntityId {get; set}
     public virtual IList<Entity> ParentEntities {get; set}
     public virtual IList<Entity> ChildEntities{get; set}
}

public class EntityLinks
{
     public virtual int EntityLinkId {get; set}
     public virtual Entity ParentEntityId {get; set}
     public virtual Entity ChildEntityId {get; set}
}
```

Here is the mapping for both the classes:

```
public class EntityMap : ClassMap<Entity>
{
  public EntityMap()
  {
    Table("Entity")
    Id(x=>x.EntityId).GeneratedBy.Increment();
    *---- How to map for ParentEntities and ChildEntites?----*
  }
}

public class EntityLinksMap : ClassMap<Entity>
{
  public EntityMap()
  {
    Table("Entity")
    Id(x=>x.EntityId).GeneratedBy.Increment();
    References(x=>x.ParentEntityId).Column("ParentEntityId");
    References(x=>x.ChildEntityId).Column("ChildEntityId");
  }
}
```

My question is how should I do mapping in entity class for ParentEntities and ChildEntites so that I get the list of both parent and child for a particular entity?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it is really good, that you are using man-in-the-middle table as a standard mapped entity.

*I am talking about the fact, that we can use mapping without that pairing table being represented as mapped entity. The syntax would be `HasManyToMany`*

But because you've chosen to have pairing table as an entity you have to change the Business model:

```
public class Entity
{
     public virtual int EntityId {get; set}
     //public virtual IList<Entity> ParentEntities {get; set}
     //public virtual IList<Entity> ChildEntities{get; set}
     public virtual IList<EntityLinks> ParentEntityLinks {get; set}
     public virtual IList<EntityLinks> ChildEntityLinks {get; set}
}
```

Mapping then would be:

```
public EntityMap()
{
     Table("Entity")
     Id(x=>x.EntityId).GeneratedBy.Increment();

     HasMany(x => x.ParentEntityLinks)...
     HasMany(x => x.ChildEntityLinks)...
}
```

More about **`HasMany`** mapping:

#### [Mapping-by-Code - Set and Bag](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/mapping-by-code-set-and-bag.html) by Adam Bar

Scroll down to **Fluent NHibernate's equivalent**:

```
HasMany(x => x.Users)
    .AsSet<CustomComparer>() // or .AsSet(), .AsBag()
    .Fetch.Join()
    .BatchSize(100)
    .LazyLoad() // or .ExtraLazyLoad()
    .Table("tableName")
    .Schema("schemaName")
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan() // or .None(), .SaveUpdate(), .All(), DeleteOrphan()
    .Inverse()
    ...
    // and many more settings
    ...
```

If in fact, you really want to keep the many-to-many, and properties like

```
 public virtual IList<Entity> ParentEntities {get; set}
 public virtual IList<Entity> ChildEntities{get; set}
```

The mapping will be

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.ParentEntities)...
HasManyToMany(x => x.ChildEntities)...
```

...which I would not suggest to use: [How to create NHibernate HasManyToMany relation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21135770/1679310) or [Nhibernate: How to represent Many-To-Many relationships with One-to-Many relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15510748/1679310), *Here are some more details how to use [HasManyToMany](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/mapping-by-code-onetomany-and-other.html) if ...*

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the mappings to be use. I was just confused in the problem at hand since this is self-referencing.

```
public class EntityMap : ClassMap<Entity>
{
  public EntityMap()
  {
    Table("Entity")
    Id(x=>x.EntityId).GeneratedBy.Increment();

   //solution mapping
    HasManyToMany(x => x.ChildEntities)
             .Table("EntityLinks")
             .ParentKeyColumn("ParentEntityId")
             .ChildKeyColumn("ChildEntityId");
        HasManyToMany(x => x.ParentEntities)
             .Table("EntityLinks")
             .ParentKeyColumn("ChildEntityId")
             .ChildKeyColumn("ParentEntityId");

  }
}

public class EntityLinksMap : ClassMap<EntityLinks>
{
  public EntityMap()
  {
    Table("EntityLinks")
    Id(x=>x.EntityId).GeneratedBy.Increment();
    References(x=>x.ParentEntityId).Column("ParentEntityId");
    References(x=>x.ChildEntityId).Column("ChildEntityId");
  }
}
```